# Change color color to another javascript no canvas

Tags: javascript

I wonder to know if it's possible to change specific color to another with javascript only to image DOM element ? (no canvas)

Thanks !

EDIT : I need to change white color of img (not background, it's transparent) to blue or green depend of player.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Emh there is no specific code I can give to you because I don't know if it's possible and how do that...
Maybe sometihing like :
var myImg = document.createElement("img");
myImg.src = "myImg.png";
myImg.color(#FFFF) = myImg.color(#0123);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css filter property for that : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp

Comment: Hmm I think it's not enought specific, I really need to change a color to another (white to blue and white to green). I add more specifications to my question.

Comment: You can try to add another element on top of an image with required background color and set opacity .8 . Something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/n6zy2Leb/